# Error when upgrade pod file to new swift version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, upgrade, swifty-json

I have error in my Xcode :

[image]

```
SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2.(in target 'SwiftyJSON')
 SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'Eureka')
SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'XLPagerTabStrip')
```

I found that I should upgrade my swift language version , but when i update this error is shown:

[image]
[image]

This is my podfile content :

```
platform :ios, '12.1'

target 'Questers' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Questers

pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'TextFieldEffects'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'XLPagerTabStrip'
pod 'Eureka' 
pod 'Charts'
pod 'Floaty'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'iOSDropDown'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'MessageKit'
pod 'MessageInputBar'

    target 'QuestersUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase'
end
```

end

Comment: You should never manually modify pods, including updating the used Swift version. Wait for the pods to be updated to Swift 5 by their maintainers or [specify the Swift compiler version to use for each pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501440/how-to-set-the-legacy-swift-version-for-each-pod-in-podfile-xcode-9-0-swift-3-2) in your podfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Your Xcode to 10.2 or manually set versions in pod as following

```
pod 'Eureka',  '~> 4.3.1'
```

When you keep pod in podfile, cocoapods installs latest version of the library.
In your case, the latest version is written in Swift 5, but your xcode does not support Swift 5, you must set the pod version for installing lib with the supported version of swift.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says the Swift compiler version 5.0 is set for **SwiftyJSON, 'Eureka', 'XLPagerTabStrip'** pods.

**Solution 1:**

Simply

1. Select the Pods project from your workspace
2. Select the above mentioned pod from the project target.
3. Under build setting search for Swift Language Version and update it to 3.0, 4.0 or 4.2.

Repeat step 2-3 for all 3 pod targets.

Set the pod specific configuration to the podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'Material'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**Solution 2:**

If the pods are using Swift 5.0 language feature in that case above solution won't work. So, update your XCode to version 10.2 that contains the Swift 5.0 APIs.
Or manually download the toolchain from [Swift 5.0](https://swift.org/download/)

Comment: Don't do that. Never modify a pod manually, since any modifications will break when you update your pods. Cocoapods supports specifying different Swift compiler versions for each pod in the podfile, so leverage that feature instead.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you are right. You can add a specification to the podfile itself, If you are following Solution 1. **I have updated the answer**