# MetaWear : Unable to build Cocoapod used in IOS application

Tags: ios, xcode

I am attempting to use the [MetaWear cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MetaWear) to connect to BLE sensors from  my IOS application. Before adding this pod, I created a basic Single View Application in Xcode. I tried to compile and run it on my iPhone, and it showed up as expected.

Having done this, I did a pod init, and updated my Podfile to look as follows, as recommended in the above MetaWear cocoapod link:

```
platform :ios, '12.2'

target 'myProj' do
     use_frameworks!
     pod 'MetaWear', '~> 3.2'
end
```

Once I run "pod install", I get the following output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Bolts-Swift (1.4.0)
Using MetaWear (3.2.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.
```

I then open my Xcode project ( myApp.xcworkspace ), and when I try to re-build the project, I keep getting this error:

```
 Could not build Objective-C module 'BoltsSwift'
```

This is also shown in the following image:

[image]

As a result, I was under the impression that maybe I should downgrade the BoltsSwift version, but specifying something lower than 1.4, seems to be ignored. For example, I added this pod:

```
pod 'Bolts-Swift', '~> 1.3'
```

And my output after running pod install, still yielded "Using Bolts-Swift (1.4.0)". So I am not too sure how to get rid of this compilation failure. Maybe downgrading BoltsSwift is not the correct course of action. What can I try? (I am using Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out that by default, XCode set my Swift compilation to 5.0 for the BoltsSwift and MetaWear pod. I changed it to Swift 4, and I was able to build.

[image]

Updating the pods compilation level might also be a good idea, as described here :

[How to set the Legacy Swift Version for each Pod in Podfile Xcode 9.0 Swift 3.2 / Swift 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501440/how-to-set-the-legacy-swift-version-for-each-pod-in-podfile-xcode-9-0-swift-3-2)